# Why can't I create a vector of threads on the fly like this

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Why is creation of vector of threads on the fly is wrong ? I am getting compilation error

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(593): error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

followed by a lot of other stuff.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::thread;
using std::cout;

class obj_on_thread {
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "obj on thread\n";
    }
};

void function_on_thread() {
    std::cout << "function on thread\n";
}

auto named_lambda = []() { std::cout << "named_lambda_on_thread\n"; };

int main(){
    obj_on_thread obj;

    vector<thread> pool {
        thread{ obj },
        thread{ function_on_thread },
        thread{ named_lambda },
        thread{ []() { cout << "anonymous lambda on thread\n"; } }
    };
    cout << "main thread\n";

    for(auto& t : pool)
    {
        if (t.joinable())
        {
            cout << "Joinable = true";
            t.join(); //if called must be called once.
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "this shouldn't get printed, joinable = false\n";
        }
    }
    for (auto& t : pool)
    {
        if (t.joinable())
        {
            cout << " This won't be printed Joinable = true";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "joinable = false thread are already joint\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They're created right there, they *are* rvalues already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector`'s constructor which uses `initializer_list` requires the elements to be copy-constructible, because `initializer_list` itself requires that (its underlying "storage" is implemented as a temporary array which is copy-constructed). `std::thread` is not copy-constructible (this constructor is deleted).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

> The underlying array is a temporary array, in which each element is
>   copy-initialized...

There's no good way to solve this problem - you cannot initialize all your threads at once, but you can use (multiple calls, one for each thread - unfortunately):

- `emplace_back()`:

  ```
  pool.emplace_back(obj);
  ```
- `push_back()` with rvalues:

  ```
  pool.push_back(thread{obj});
  ```
- `push_back()` with explicit `move()`s:

  ```
  auto t = thread{obj};
  pool.push_back(std::move(t));
  ```

Comment: .... which is so stupid. You can have an upvote if you suggest a way to fix it (i.e. likely `emplace_back`).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hold on your horses... I am adding comment to the post..and I am free to up vote as I like

Comment: I see then way to fix is using push_back(std::thread(...)) or emplace_back etc.

Comment: @cpp_hex - `push_back` will only work if you use rvalues (or `move` the objects), but `emplace_back` is OK.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - done, no need to argue (; Initially I decided that the OP did not ask how to fix it, just why there is an error.

Comment: ++1: It's complete now. :)